# Array push not working inside promise then

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I can't see what I'm doing wrong...push not working and returns nothing

```
import {nearbyUsers, getLatitude, getLongitude} from './helper'
const users = []
nearbyUsers(session, getLatitude(), getLongitude()).then(res => {
    users.push(res)
console.log(users.lenght) //this works fine
})

console.log(users.lenght) //this prints 0
```

Comment: `console.log(users.lenght)` will never print anything but `undefined`

Comment: It's `length` and not `lenght`. Anyway, the issue is that the second console.log returns 0 because the callback hasn't executed yet. Your code is asynchronous.

Answer (score -3):

The problem is that the `then` callback happens asynchronously, meaning that there may (and probably will) be a delay between when the code inside the then callback is executed and the rest of the code outside of it.

If you want to depend on an async function, be sure to read about async/await. The await keyword, when put before an async function, will halt the program until the promise is resolved.

For more see [here](https://youtu.be/vn3tm0quoqE) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)